# python: call a parent class' recursive function

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I cannot quite understand the following result:

```py
class A:
    def a(self, i):
        if i <= 0:
            return
        print("A", i)
        self.a(i - 1)  # line 6


class B(A):
    def a(self, i):
        print("B", i)
        super().a(i)   # line 12


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.a(3)
```

result is:

```
B 3
A 3
B 2
A 2
B 1
A 1
B 0
```

In line 12, it calls the parent class A's function, however when `a()` recursively call itself, it uses the B's version. Why it happens?

How can I get the following result (I still want to override parent's function `a()`):

```
B 3
A 3
A 2
A 1
```

I want to force the instance only uses function in parent's version.

I have this requirement since I meet similar problem in some practical problem. I still have to name the function as `a` in class `B`. However most part of logic is duplicate in `A` and I want to reuse it.

Right now I can only use the following way to implement `B`:

```
class B(A):
    def a(self, i):
        print("B", i)
        self.a_helper(i) 

    def a_helper(self, i):
        if i <= 0:
            return
        print("A", i)
        self.a_helper(i - 1)
```

Comment: Methods are looked up based on the class of the object, not the class where the method is defined. Since `self` is a `B` instance, `self.a()` calls the `B` method.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. Then how to handle the second question?

Comment: Don't override method `a` in class B. Perhaps call the method a different name.

Comment: You can call methods directly: `A.a(self, i)`

Comment: But this negates some of the benefits of OOP. Subclasses are supposed to be able to override the parent methods.

Comment: @quamrana I updated my question. I have a practical use case: I have to name it as `a()` in B

Comment: There is another option: Don't inherit from `A`. That way, you *can* have your `B` class implement a method named `a`. You would then need an instance of `A` as an attribute of `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method directly as an ordinary function, rather than going through the instance.

```
class A:
    def a(self, i):
        if i <= 0:
            return
        print("A", i)
        A.a(self, i - 1)  # line 6
```